# How to work with dependencies in a Django project deployed on Openshift

Tags: pip, openshift, virtualenv

I recently started using Django. I am working on a simple web app that will have a web crawler functionality. One of the packages I am using is **Requests**. On my local machine all works fine, but I would like to understand how should I go about the packages when pushing it to production? Just adding the packages names and version to requirements.txt is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough. I am using `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Digrin',
    version='2.0',
    description='Dividend growth investing',
    author='name',
    author_email='l@gmail.com',
    url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
    install_requires=['Django==1.8.7', 'django_haystack==2.4.0', 'whoosh==2.7.0', 'django-allauth==0.23',
                      'django-bootstrap3==5.4.0', 'django_crontab==0.6.0',
                      'xlrd==0.9.3', 'scipy==0.12.1', 'django-debug-toolbar==1.3.0', 'BeautifulSoup4==4.3.2',
                      'python-dateutil==2.2', 'opbeat', 'django-markdown-deux==1.0.5', 'markdown2'],
```

Requirements should work the same way. `setup.py` file is located next to `wsgi` directory. I believe for `requirements.txt` it should be the same. You may also check some of examples for [openshift and django](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17), that might save you some time.